# Android Push Notification : Create for simple wordpress page

Tags: android

I'm working on my school project. I need to push notifications to the users who have the app installed in their smartphone. My brother told me that i can do so by simply creating wordpress page and something like that. But I'm totally novice in this field so can you please guide me on this?

Comment: Are you referring to the Wordpress official app or an app you built yourself that needs to have notifications?

Answer (score 0):

<s>Since you are talking about an app you built, Wordpress doesn't have notifications out-of-the-box for Google Cloud Messaging. There is a plugin (which has a free limited version) called [Push Notifications for Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/push-notifications-for-wp/) which sounds like exactly what you are wanting.</s>

---

**Android WebView Code Example:**

```
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, final String url, String message, JsResult result) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage(message)
                .setNeutralButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        arg0.dismiss();
                   }
                }).show();
        result.cancel();
        return true;
    }
});
```

**Custom JavaScript:**

```
alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
```

Comment: See the idea is that my app has a fragment called Notifications it will show the wordpress page(will give a link to that page). The only purpose of push notification is to show that something has been updated on the notification page just by saying "New Notification please check".

Comment: I'm assuming this is a WebView of that page and would probably be better if you did some custom HTML & CSS inside the page to show a javascript dialog box to the user via a custom WebChromeClient of the WebView.

Comment: you are using some technical terms that i have never heard of, is there any tutorial or any walk through for this